# Making result to look in one single output using two select statements which has where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

I start query with select(table1) and end up with where statements and then again start with select(table2) with where statements, Please have a look at the image and and let me know , how to do it , Thank you

Query is below and outputs i get is also below.

```
--//1st select statement //

SELECT
    Measure          = CASE WHEN abd.dosiqID = 'A321'
                                THEN 'C-DIFF'
                           WHEN abd.dosiqID = 'B43'
                               THEN 'MRSA'
                           WHEN abd.dosiqID = 'bill'
                               THEN 'CAUTI'
                           WHEN abd.dosiqID = 'rewq'
                               THEN 'CLABSI'
                       END
    ,SoundPatients   = ram.AccountNumber
    ,DIAG            = abd.dosiqID
    ,SoundPhysicians = rapd.Admitid
    ,LenOfStay       = (CASE WHEN ram.AdmitDateTime IS NULL
                                 THEN 1
                            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, ram.AdmitDateTime, COALESCE(vd.DischargeDateTime, GETDATE())) < 1
                                THEN 1
                            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, ram.AdmitDateTime, COALESCE(vd.DischargeDateTime, GETDATE()))
                        END
                       )
    ,Pt_Status       = ram.RegistID
INTO sphy
FROM livefdb.dbo.REVERGE_REG     ram
LEFT JOIN livefdb.dbo.ReProrData p ON p.SourceID = ram.SourceID
                                       AND p.VisitID = ram.VisitID
LEFT JOIN livefdb.dbo.HiData     vd ON vd.SourceID = ram.SourceID
                                        AND vd.PatientID = ram.PatientID
                                        AND vd.VisitID = ram.VisitID
                                        AND vd.VisitType_MisRegTypeID = ram.RegistID
JOIN Abgnes                      abd ON abd.SourceID = ram.SourceID
                                         AND abd.VisitID = ram.VisitID
JOIN ReProrData                  rapd ON rapd.SourceID = ram.SourceID
                                          AND rapd.VisitID = ram.VisitID
LEFT OUTER JOIN AbsAcct_Main     abm ON abm.SourceID = ram.SourceID
                                         AND abm.VisitID = ram.VisitID
WHERE
    CAST(ram.AdmitDateTime AS DATE) BETWEEN '20180401' AND '20180930'
    AND ram.Facility_MisFacID IN ('mha', 'bha')
    AND abd.dosiqID IN ('999.32', '996.64', '041.12', '008.45', 'A321', 'B43', 'bill', 'rewq')
    AND rapd.Admitid IN ('DOC1', 'DOC2', 'DOC3', 'DOC4', 'DOC5', 'DOC6', 'DOC7', 'DOC8', 'DOC9')
    AND ram.RegistID IN ('IN', 'INO')


--//2nd select statement //

SELECT
    Measure          = CASE WHEN abd.dosiqID = 'A321'
                                THEN 'C-DIFF'
                           WHEN abd.dosiqID = 'B43'
                               THEN 'MRSA'
                           WHEN abd.dosiqID = 'bill'
                               THEN 'CAUTI'
                           WHEN abd.dosiqID = 'rewq'
                               THEN 'CLABSI'
                       END
    ,TotalPatients   = ram.AccountNumber
    ,DIAG            = abd.dosiqID
    ,SoundPhysicians = rapd.Admitid
    ,LenOfStay       = (CASE WHEN ram.AdmitDateTime IS NULL
                                 THEN 1
                            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, ram.AdmitDateTime, COALESCE(vd.DischargeDateTime, GETDATE())) < 1
                                THEN 1
                            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, ram.AdmitDateTime, COALESCE(vd.DischargeDateTime, GETDATE()))
                        END
                       )
    ,Pt_Status       = ram.RegistID
INTO sphy2
FROM livefdb.dbo.REVERGE_REG     ram
LEFT JOIN livefdb.dbo.ReProrData p ON p.SourceID = ram.SourceID
                                       AND p.VisitID = ram.VisitID
LEFT JOIN livefdb.dbo.HiData     vd ON vd.SourceID = ram.SourceID
                                        AND vd.PatientID = ram.PatientID
                                        AND vd.VisitID = ram.VisitID
                                        AND vd.VisitType_MisRegTypeID = ram.RegistID
JOIN Abgnes                      abd ON abd.SourceID = ram.SourceID
                                         AND abd.VisitID = ram.VisitID
JOIN ReProrData                  rapd ON rapd.SourceID = ram.SourceID
                                          AND rapd.VisitID = ram.VisitID
WHERE
    CAST(ram.AdmitDateTime AS DATE) BETWEEN '20180401' AND '20180930'
    AND ram.Facility_MisFacID IN ('mha', 'bha')
    AND abd.dosiqID IN ('A321', 'B43', 'bill', 'rewq')
    AND ram.RegistID IN ('IN', 'INO')


DROP TABLE sphy
DROP TABLE sphy2

END 
GO
```

Aggregate queries on intermediate results:

```
SELECT
    Measure
    ,SoundPatients    = COUNT(*)
    ,TotalPatientDays = SUM(LenOfStay)
FROM Sphy
GROUP BY Measure
ORDER BY Measure

SELECT
    Measure
    ,TotalPatients    = COUNT(*)
    ,TotalPatientDays = SUM(LenOfStay)
FROM Sphy2
GROUP BY Measure
ORDER BY Measure
```

Current outputs:

```
Measure    SoundPatients    TotalPatientDays
CLABSI         6                   49 
MRSA          33                  219

Measure  TotalPatients    TotalPatientDays
CLABSI      6                49
MRSA        44               290
```

My desired output is:

```
Measure    SoundPatients    TotalPatients   TotalPatientDays
CLABSI        6                6                49
MRSA          33               44               290
```

**Please remember that i need count of data and sum of lenofstay. and let me know if any additional issues or queries , and help me in that **

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Update your post please by not using images, and display  what you want in the post.

Comment: I think you need a left join

Comment: Please post the queries you used. You will get answer quickly

Comment: Edited my question , now let me know/. .

Comment: @Madhivanan edited question

Comment: i should get count for soundpatinets and Total patients and sum for totalpatientdays which is lenofstay

Comment: @Madhivanan , ASKED TO POST THE QUERY , NOW NO HELP AT ALL

Comment: @kreme123 Just because somebody asks you to post more information does no mean that they will respond as soon as you do, or even respond at all. Most people who `volunteer` their time to help others have full time jobs and other commitments. Please show respect to other members if you expect to get any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the two results on the on the `Measure` field. Since `sphy` seems to be a subset of `sphy2`, the join should use all records from the sphy2-side:

```
WITH
  output1 (Measure, SoundPatients, TotalPatientDays) AS (
    SELECT Measure, COUNT(*), SUM(LenOfStay) FROM Sphy
    GROUP BY Measure
  ),
  output2 (Measure, TotalPatients, TotalPatientDays) AS (
    SELECT Measure, COUNT(*), SUM(LenOfStay) FROM Sphy2
    GROUP BY Measure
  )
SELECT o2.Measure, o1.SoundPatients, o2.TotalPatients, o2.TotalPatientDays
FROM output2 o2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN output1 o1 ON o2.Measure = o1.Measure
ORDER BY o2.Measure;
```

Comment: If you want to Export the final result, specify the whole statement (starting with `WITH`) for your BCP command. But I don't think that the command will work, because "L" looks to me like a mapped network drive that *you* see, but SQL Server most probably won't. You will have to use an UNC path instead.

Answer (score 0):

Lack of logic,

```
select t1.Measure,
 t1.SoundPatients,
 t2.TotalPatients,
 iif ( t1.TotalPatientsDays > t2.TotalPatientsDays ,t1.TotalPatientsDays ,
       t2.TotalPatientsDays
     ) 
 TotalPatientsDays
from   table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.Measure = t2.Measure
```

**Edit 1:**

```
;with o1 as (
 -- your query
)
,o2 as (
 -- your query
)select * into o from o1 join o2 on o1.id = o2.id

declare @server varchar (max) = @@SERVERNAME -- server name has been taken dynamically.
, @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp trainee1.dbo.o out "path\smph_SoundPhy2.csv" -c -t, -T -S "' + @server +  '"''' -- here your DB name and path
print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: @kreme123 place your first query on `table1` enclosed by `()` and second query on `table2` and enclosed by `()`.... let me know that's why your columns are not in query on updated question.

Comment: @kreme123 go with [him](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704928/making-result-to-look-in-one-single-output-using-two-select-statements-which-has/52710716#52710716)

Comment: I use bcp commands in the bottom to generate output to csv and what is the table should I use in this line for this query?                   
 exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from livefdb.dbo.o2" queryout "L:\sphy\mph_SoundPhy.csv" -T -c -t "," -S server2'

Comment: @kreme123... [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704928/making-result-to-look-in-one-single-output-using-two-select-statements-which-has/52705183#52705183)